# Where to put hashtag in Ajax url

Tags: ajax, url, hashtag

I used to put my url like this :

```
example.com/#!ajaxcall/parent/child
```

but then, google gave me warning says that my url "is not followed" :

> When we tested a sample of URLs from your Sitemap, we found that some
>   URLs redirect to other locations. We recommend that your Sitemap
>   contain URLs that point to the final destination (the redirect target)
>   instead of redirecting to another URL.

so i changed my url into :

```
example.com/parent/child/#!ajaxcall/
```

after changing the url, i keep getting 404 error(because the hashchange event never fired), i don't know what am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `#!`? Do you have a static renderer? read https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started for more info

Comment: thanks Pumbaa, 

i've successed to get Google to crawl my site after reading the url you just gave me !